# How many additional numbers can I set in one contact?

Tags: iphone

As the title says, how many additional numbers can I set in one contact? I was playing around with a script and I was able to get even 2000 of them in on an iPhone 6 simulator. However, would like some official response about what is the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit as to how many numbers you can get on a contact.

Comment: could you please back that up with some official documentation? Not that I don't trust you, it's asked of me.

Comment: @Nikola there is a limit, it's whenever you run out of storage space to put the numbers.